# A 2/3-good coloring of graph vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Is it always possible to color the vertices of a graph such that:

- at least $2/3$ of the edges touch a blue vertex, and
- at least $2/3$ of the edges touch a red vertex?

Note: the fraction $2/3$ comes from the triangle graph: there, if we color two vertices red and one blue, then *exactly* $2/3$ of the edges touch a blue vertex. In other graphs that I tried, usually it is possible to color the vertices such that more than $2/3$ of the edges touch each color.

Comment: The totally disconnected graph also fits exactly the two-thirds bound (since two-thirds of zero is zero, which is equal to zero...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is true. Take a maximum edge cut in your graph $G$, and label the vertices on one side of the cut $R$ and the other side $B$. This gives a partition of the edges into three sets $E(R), E(B), X$ where $E(R),E(B)$ are those edges with both ends in $R$ and $B$, respectively, and $X$ are the edges with one end in each. Because $X$ is a max cut, you know that for any vertex $v\in R$, $v$ has at least as many neighbours in $B$ as it has in $R$ (otherwise you would move $v$ to $B$ and get a better cut.) Summing over all vertices in $R$, it follows that $|X| \geq 2|E(R)|$.

On the other hand, $|X| + |E(R)| \leq |E(G)|$. Combining the latter two inequalities gives: $2|E(R)| \leq |E(G)| - |E(R)|$ so $|E(R)|\leq \frac13|E(G)|$. Therefore $|E(B)|+ |X|\geq \frac23|E(G)|$. By symmetry also $|E(R)| + X \geq \frac23 |E(G)|$.

Comment: Cool proof! Thanks